# JVM state determined to be unstable. Exiting forcefully. what is Java Stability Inspector ?? why it is stopping DSE?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

From last few days i am seeing on some of the nodes in cassandra cluster DSE is getting shutdown due to the error below and i need to kill Java process and restart DSE service.

I have cross checked reads and writes and compactions nothing looks suspicious, but i am seeing full Gc pause on these server just before the issue happening. what can be the reason for this how to debug that ?? how to fine grain why on those particular nodes this is happening when these nodes are serving same requests like rest of the cluster ??

Is this happening because of  Full Gc is not getting performed properly, we using G1GC and DSE 4.8.3

```
    ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-25] 2016-12-27 10:14:26,100  JVMStabilityInspector.java:117 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeTombstoneList.copy(RangeTombstoneList.java:112) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.DeletionInfo.copy(DeletionInfo.java:104) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicBTreeColumns.addAllWithSizeDelta(AtomicBTreeColumns.java:217) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:210) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1230) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:396) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:359) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:214) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.MutationVerbHandler.doVerb(MutationVerbHandler.java:54) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:64) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
            at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]

    ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-25] 2016-12-27 10:14:28,100  SEPWorker.java:141 - Failed to execute task, unexpected exception killed worker: {}
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
            at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.remove(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
            at java.lang.Runtime.removeShutdownHook(Runtime.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.removeShutdownHook(StorageService.java:764) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector$Killer.killCurrentJVM(JVMStabilityInspector.java:119) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector$Killer.killCurrentJVM(JVMStabilityInspector.java:109) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:68) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131]
            at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:168) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131] 
at 
org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1131.jar:2.1.13.1131] 
at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]

    INFO  [Thread-6] 2016-12-27 10:14:56,150  DseDaemon.java:420 - DSE shutting down...
```

Comment: It's an out of memory exception, how big is your heap?

Comment: @phact Heap is 12Gb and new heap is 4Gb.

Comment: Are you using Search?

Comment: A good way to find out what filled up your heap is to introspect your heap dump. .Hprof file

Comment: Another good way is to monitor hot threads as you approach the oom

Comment: @phact just cassandra not using search, is this any way caused because of incomplete GC or any thing like that ?? or  because of host ran out of heap memory ??

Comment: The latter, out of heap memory

Comment: Hello, I also got the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you any large partitions are present in the Cassandra tables and if any queries are reading lot of tombstones.